# Upload text logs to MVC 4 web server every second

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, logging

I have a Web Server implemented using dot net MVC4. There are clients connected to this web server which perform some operations and upload live logs to the server using WebClient.UploadString method. Sending these logs from client to server is being done in group of 2500 characters at a time.

Things work fine until 2-3 client upload logs. However when more than 3 clients try to upload logs simultaneously they start receiving "http 500 internal server error".
I might have to scale up and add more slaves but that will make the situation worse.

I want to implement Jenkins like live logging, where logs from slave are updated live.

Please suggest some better and scalable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered looking into [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr)?

It can be used for anything from instant messaging to stocks! I have implemented both a chatbox, and a custom system that sends off messages, does calculations and then passes them back down to client. It is very reliable, there are some nice tutorials, and I think it's awesome.